Вознкиает ошибка при запуске игры в Wine
Запускаю игру PROGRESS BAR 95 и когда выбираю систему все зависает на загрузке, а в консоле такая ошибка:
WARNING: audio.loadStream() failed to create stream 'sound/pb_theme_pc_speaker.'
ERROR: Runtime error
D:\a\corona\corona\platform\resources\init.lua:234: Warning: audio.getDuration:)
    
stack traceback:
      [C]: in function 'error'
      D:\a\corona\corona\platform\resources\init.lua:234: in function <D:\a\c>
Error =rces\init.lua:234: Warning: audio.getDuration: invalid sound object 0000)
    
StackTrace =rces\init.lua:234: in function <D:\a\corona\corona\platform\resourc>


Я довольно много времени потратил на запуск MS Visio он целом нормально работал но формы настроек отображались криво. Я скормил этот момент (вызова форм) в phind и получил наколку на библиотеку вызывающую вызов заглушки. попробуйте затолкать логи wine в разные нейронки возможно также в их датасетах есть полезные наколки на вашу проблему
